# Performance testing on .xap files

Tags: xap, visual-studio-2010

I want to know that can i use profiler to do performance testing of .xap files. if you have any articles for the same topic please provide it to me.

and if there are any other tools available to do this please tell me.

in my project we have to check that when we logged into the Silverlight 4 .0 application. the screen takes 5 seconds to load. so i have to check which method is taking time to do this.

in our project there are services which calls other services too,,
and we have used CAL. so need to identify the bottleneck... please help...

Answer (score 0):

[EQATEC Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com) is free and can profile xap-files. See eg this [review](http://www.ingebrigtsen.info/post/2010/02/24/First-go-with-the-EQATEC-Silverlight-Profiler.aspx).